# Using maven just for dependency management

Tags: maven, build, ant, dependency-management

In our project we are using ant for building the system and now we want to add dependency management to our system. I already learn that we can use ivy for this. But in future, we want to change the system into maven. But for now, we just want to handle the dependency problem. Is it possible to use maven just for dependency management and build for ant?

Comment: Do you do any "complicated" things in Ant? Otherwise, I would just completely rewrite the project to using Maven instead of trying to build a hybrid. If you have some specific step that you need to run in ant, you can use the Maven Antrun Plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are using ant for the build system. It's already testing some things and sending project jars to a specific folder. But I didn't know the antRun plugin appreciate you for that.